# Run nodejs http-server as a windows service

Tags: node.js, windows, http, server, httpserver

I want to run nodejs http-server which serves a static file as a windows service which autostarts on boot. How do we keep this server running in background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/).

You usually need a windows service to be destined for being a server, this is a service manager that works as a service and lets you make simple apps into windows services.